# error: value trainModel is not a member of hex.tree.gbm.GBM

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, h2o, gbm, sparkling-water

When I try to add H2O with spark and use GBM model. I'm getting this exception while packaging it. This is my first time running H2O with spark. And I just tried adding the H2O libraries in my spark app and used the GBM within H2O.

Comment: Found it - Need to add h2o-core in the dependency although it is implicitly referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are building application on top of Spark and Sparkling Water please look at Sparkling Water droplet - which describes an example of configuration via Gradle or Sbt: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-droplets/tree/master/sparkling-water-droplet

You need to make sure that you have all Sparkling Water libraries and required dependencies (including `h2o-core`, `h2o-algos`).